# Generate ,pom file from jar in artifactory?

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, artifactory

I have legacy code which is packaged in jar and deployed to artifactory from jenkins job. The jar creation is done using "java -jar" command. The .pom file is not generated in the process. Is there a way to auto-generate .pom file in the artifactory when we deploy jar from jenkins?

Based on this post, we can not :

http://forums.jfrog.org/Auto-create-pom-when-jar-is-deployed-td7578061.html

This is somewhat old post though. I was wondering if there is any new development that enables auto-generating .pom. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about automatic pom creation , but you create a small bash / groovy task that will generate the basic pom.xml.

just update the version ( you can use the build number from Jenkins) ,and upload the created pom with your jar.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
<artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
<version>1.2.buildNumber</version>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting using a template .pom file in the format above and then replace the parameters (artifactId, groupId etc.) into it with each build?